# how to parse hostname from a line

Tags: bash, grep

I have a line :

> Check space in www.raja.server.local.com and it is 40% full in /usr

I want to just parse **www.raja.server.local.com** from above line.

Note: www.raja.server.local.com can be any where in the line.

Comment: This question makes no sense unless the hostname changes with different lines.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 Hello there , hostname will change but local.com will not change. It will exist in everyline but position of the local.com can be any where in the line

Answer (score 1):

If your question can be reworded as "print all space-separated fields
ending in `.local.com`", then the following should do it (using GNU
grep):

```
grep -Eo '[^ ]+\.local\.com\b'
```

Comment: No , everytime it will not be 4th field .

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully match your clarified question.

Comment: I will check and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Fragile, but it's an answer...

```
awk '/\.local\.com/ { x=gensub(/.* ([^\ ]+\.local\.com).*/,"\\1","1"); print x }'
```

*A better solution would be to use back references.*